# Convert QString date (RFC 822 format) to another QString format based on culture

Tags: c++, qt, date, datetime, date-conversion

I've a database with multiple strings, I get this records from query, and i receive this format data in QString:

> "Mon, 13 Nov 2017 09:48:45 +0000"

So, I need to convert this based on culture, for example if I want convert in italian culture?

So the result will be:

> "Lun, 13 Nov 2017 09:48:45"

Exist in qt this type of conversion or I have to proceed manually ?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt provides the [`QLocale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html) class to handle language/country specifics. It has overloads of `QLocale::toString()` that accept `QDateTime`.

It also has a function `QLocale::toDateTime()` to do the reverse operation. But in your case the non local aware `QDateTime::fromString()` should work.

Int the end you should have something like this (+ or - some parameters for the exact format you want).

```
QString source = "Mon, 13 Nov 2017 09:48:45 +0000";
QDateTime dt  = QDateTime::fromString(source, Qt::RFC2822Date);
QString result = QLocale().toString(dt, Qt::RFC2822Date);
```

Note that `QLocale()` constructs an instance based on the current user setting in the underlying OS. You can also force a specific language/country, for instance: `QLocale(QLocale::Italian)`.

Comment: QDateTime::fromSource doesn't have in my library...maybe I need to add a library in particulary ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer It's a typo. It is `fromString()` as quoted in the paragraph above.

Comment: have you tried this code ? Because QDateTime dt return Invalid

Comment: @Mr.Developer That's because you need to add `some parameters for the exact format you want`. See Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1

Comment: Yes thanks it works, i add Qt::RFC2822Date in the format request parameter and now works, can you add this in you code ? Qt::RFC2822Date thanks